# Помогите с объяснением задачи

Tags: python

Задача "Заполнение змейкой"
**Условие:**
По данным числам nn и mm заполните двумерный массив размером n×m числами от 1 до n×mn×m “змейкой”, как показано в примере.
[image: входные и выходные данные]

```
n = int(input('Введите число строк(n) ')) 
m = int(input('Введите число столбцов(m) '))
for j in range(n):
        print(' '.join([str(i + 1 + m * j) for i in range(m)][::pow(-1, j)]))
```

Пожалуйста, подробно объясните решение данной задачи. Как можно подробнее. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

надо заполнить матрицу сначала слева направо, потом справа налево, потом слева направо и т.д.

сначала проходим по всем строкам (`n` штук)

```
for j in range(n):
```

для каждой строки формируем строку в виде списка чисел (вернее чисел переведённых в строки)

```
[str(i + 1 + m * j) for i in range(m)][::pow(-1, j)]
```

потом все числа из списка соединяем в одну строку через разделитель пробел

текущий номер числа вычисляется по формуле:

```
i + 1 + m * j
```

для всех нечётных строк переворачивается сформированная строка

```
[::pow(-1, j)]
```

это срез строки в которую входят все символы строки, но в обратном направлении, если `j` нечётное иначе в прямом направлении

**P.S.**

кстати можно обойтись и без `join` и без срезов строки:

т.е. можно все сделать одной формулой

```
for j in range(n):
        print(*[j * m + i + 1 + (j % 2) * (m - 2 * i - 1) for i in range(m)], sep=' ')
```

т.е. формируется строка чисел (именно чисел, а не строк) и выводится через разделитель пробел

Comment: join — метод для работы со строками, позволяет включать в строку элементы, например, объектов типа list. При этом добавляются любые разделители.